# Microsoft botframework and Slack configuration

Tags: botframework, slack

I'm using Microsoft's botframework to create a Slack bot, however I'm running into 2 problems.

1. When I do "Test connection to your bot" I'm getting

`InternalServerError
  no_text`

2. When I type in the test chat console on the botframework page, the messages are received in my slack general channel. However, when I as a user in my slack and type in the general channel, whatever I type the bot also generate the same message. i.e.

`me: Hello`

`bot: Hello`

I think it's how I set up my configuration for the slack bot app and/or the messaging endpoint of my botframework bot.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it's probably how you deal with messages in your code rather than configuration. Can you post the code that handles messages?

Comment: I created a slack bot today, with the BotFramework, and haven't seen these issues.  It would be easier to assist you if we could see the code (as requested by @AnnaZietlow )